# Selenium code not working on Safari browser

Tags: selenium, safari

I have written the following code to select Account - Register menu option in http://www.snapdeal.com

```
public void selectRegisterAccount(String object){
        System.out.println(object);
        writeLog("Executing keyword selectRegisterAccount");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            actions = new Actions(browser);
            actions.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath(project.getProperty("XPath_linkAccount")))).perform();
            actions.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath(project.getProperty("XPath_linkRegister")))).click().build().perform();
            browser.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
            currentElement = browser.findElement(By.xpath(project.getProperty(object)));
            browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Assert.assertNotNull(currentElement,"Failed to open Register page.");
            writeLog("Failed to open Register page because of "+e.getMessage());
        }
        writeLog("Ending keyword selectRegisterAccount");
    }
```

My project properties is as follows

```
testSiteURL = http://www.snapdeal.com

#####################################################################################################################################
            ************************************************BUTTONS************************************************************
#####################################################################################################################################
XPath_btnPinCodeClose = //*[@id='pincodeSalienceComponent']/div[2]/i
XPath_btnMobileNumberEmail = //*[@id='login-register-modal']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div

#####################################################################################################################################
            ************************************************HEADINGS************************************************************
#####################################################################################################################################
XPath_headingRegister = //*[@id='login-register-modal']/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]

#####################################################################################################################################
            ************************************************INPUTS************************************************************
#####################################################################################################################################
XPath_txtRegisterMobile = //*[@id='j_number']
XPath_txtRegisterEmail = //*[@id='j_username_new']
XPath_txtRegisterPassword = //*[@id='j_password']
XPath_txtRegisterConfPassword = //*[@id='j_confpassword']
XPath_txtRegisterPinCode = //*[@id='j_pincode']

#####################################################################################################################################
            ************************************************LINKS************************************************************
#####################################################################################################################################
XPath_linkAccount = //*[@id='accountHeader']/div[1]
XPath_linkRegister = //*[@id='accountHeader']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p/span[2]

#####################################################################################################################################
            ************************************************TITLES************************************************************
#####################################################################################################################################
Title_homePage = Shop Online in India at Snapdeal - India's Largest Shopping Site
```

The above code works fine with Chrome and Mozilla, but when executed for Safari I see the below exception

```
2016-03-20 19:22:57,373 DEBUG [RegisterTest - 2] Executing keyword selectRegisterAccount
2016-03-20 19:22:58,423 DEBUG [RegisterTest - 2] Failed to open Register page because of Unknown command: {"id":"n4vqmxrlur2e","name":"mouseMoveTo","parameters":{"element":":wdc:1458481961848"}} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'Srini-PC', ip: '10.0.0.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=5.1.7, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=WINDOWS, secureSsl=true}]
Session ID: null
2016-03-20 19:22:58,424 DEBUG [RegisterTest - 2] Ending keyword selectRegisterAccount
```

Comment: Why do you want to test Safari on windows knowing that it hasn't be updated since 2014?

Comment: You're probably looking at < 0.1% market share.

Comment: I even tested this code on my Macbook and encountering the same problem.